# How to mimic geom_boxplot() with outliers using geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, dplyr

I would like to pre-compute by-variable summaries of data (with `plyr` and passing a `quantile` function) and then plot with `geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")`. This works great except it (a) does not plot outliers as points and (b) extends the "whiskers" to the max and min of the data being plotted.

Example:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(fact = sample(letters[1:2], 12, replace = TRUE),
                 val  = c(1:10, 100, 101))
df
#    fact val
# 1     b   1
# 2     a   2
# 3     a   3
# 4     a   4
# 5     b   5
# 6     a   6
# 7     b   7
# 8     b   8
# 9     b   9
# 10    a  10
# 11    b 100
# 12    a 101

by.fact.df <- ddply(df, c("fact"), function(x) quantile(x$val))

by.fact.df
#   fact 0%  25% 50%  75% 100%
# 1    a  2 3.25 5.0 9.00  101
# 2    b  1 5.50 7.5 8.75  100

# What I can do...with faults (a) and (b) above
ggplot(by.fact.df, 
       aes(x = fact, ymin = `0%`, lower = `25%`, middle = `50%`, 
           upper = `75%`,  ymax = `100%`)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")

# What I want...
ggplot(df, aes(x = fact, y = val)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

What I can do...with faults (a) and (b) mentioned above:

[image: Plot 01]

What I would like to obtain, but still leverage pre-computation via `plyr` (or other method):

[image: Plot 02]

**Initial Thoughts:** Perhaps there is some way to pre-compute the true end-points of the whiskers without the outliers? Then, subset the data for outliers and pass them as `geom_point()`?

**Motivation:** When working with larger datasets, I have found it faster and more practical to leverage `plyr`, `dplyr`, and/or `data.table` to pre-compute the stats and then plot them rather than having `ggplot2` to the calculations.

### UPDATE

I am able to extract what I need with the following mix of `dplyr` and `plyr` code, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way:

```
df %>%
  group_by(fact) %>%
  do(ldply(boxplot.stats(.$val), data.frame))

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: fact

  fact   .id X..i..
1    a stats      2
2    a stats      4
3    a stats     10
4    a stats     13
5    a stats     16
6    a     n      9
```

Comment: use dplyr (faster than plyr) and look up `?boxplot.stats` and incorporate that in your function

Comment: @infominer this is helpful, any thoughts of how to handle how `boxplot.stats` outputs the outliers? That is, each factor could have various lengths of outliers?

Comment: just writing up my answer! @shadow's answer is good, it takes care of the gggplot implementation of boxplot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my answer, using built-in functions `quantile` and `boxplot.stats`.

`geom_boxplot` does the calcualtions for boxplot slightly differently than `boxplot.stats`. Read `?geom_boxplot` and `?boxplot.stats` to understand my implementation below

```
#Function to calculate boxplot stats to match ggplot's implemention as in geom_boxplot.
my_boxplot.stats <-function(x){
        quantiles <-quantile(x, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))
        labels <-names(quantile(x))
        #replacing the upper whisker to geom_boxplot
        quantiles[5] <-boxplot.stats(x)$stats[5]
        res <-data.frame(rbind(quantiles))
        names(res) <-labels
        res$out <-boxplot.stats(x)$out
        return(res)
    }
```

Code to calculate the stats and plot it

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(fact) %>% do(my_boxplot.stats(.$val)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=fact, y=out, ymin = `0%`, lower = `25%`, middle = `50%`,
                 upper = `75%`,  ymax = `100%`)) +
      geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") + geom_point()
```

Comment: This is a much nicer answer than mine. But right now this only works as long as you only have one outlier per group. If you have multiple outliers, you can put the result in a list `res <- as.list(quantiles)` before adding the outliers. And afterwards you convert into a `data.frame`. If you have many outliers, it may actually be better to calculate a `data.frame` with the main statistics and a seperate `data.frame` with the outliers.

Answer (score 2):

To get the correct statistics, you have to do some more calculations than just finding the quantiles. The `geom_boxplot` function with `stat = "identity"` does not draw the outliers. So you have to calculate the statistics without the outliers and then use `geom_point` to draw the outliers seperately. The following function (basically a simplified version of `stat_boxplot`) is probably not the most efficient, but it gives the desired result:

```
box.df <- df %>% group_by(fact) %>% do({
  stats <- as.numeric(quantile(.$val, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)))
  iqr <- diff(stats[c(2, 4)])
  coef <- 1.5
  outliers <- .$val < (stats[2] - coef * iqr) | .$val > (stats[4] + coef * iqr)
  if (any(outliers)) {
    stats[c(1, 5)] <- range(c(stats[2:4], .$val[!outliers]), na.rm=TRUE)
  }
  outlier_values = .$val[outliers]
  if (length(outlier_values) == 0) outlier_values <- NA_real_
  res <- as.list(t(stats))
  names(res) <- c("lower.whisker", "lower.hinge", "median", "upper.hinge", "upper.whisker")
  res$out <- outlier_values
  as.data.frame(res)
})
box.df
## Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
## Groups: fact
## 
##   fact lower.whisker lower.hinge median upper.hinge upper.whisker out
## 1    a             2        3.25    5.0        9.00            10 101
## 2    b             1        5.50    7.5        8.75             9 100

ggplot(box.df, aes(x = fact, y = out, middle = median,
                   ymin = lower.whisker, ymax = upper.whisker,
                   lower = lower.hinge, upper = upper.hinge)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks @shadow +1 - I hate reinventing the wheel - perhaps there's a way to leverage `boxplot.stats` - see my update and @infominer's comment.