# Use of custom median and quartile functions for ggplot2 boxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I need to visualize distributions of circular values using boxplots.
My values are distributed among the hours of the day (with 0 h = 24 h):

```
value <- c(18.8,1.2,4.4,3.8,3.4,0.2,2.8,2.3,4.8,7.8,21.5,1.5,22.2,23.4,1.6,19.9,0.5,20.5,21.1,22.2,18.7,17.1,16.7,16.4,16.3,18.1,15.7,18.9,16.7,15.2)
condition <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",10), rep("C",10))
df <- cbind.data.frame(condition, value)
```

I would like to use the `circular` R package to compute the circular median and the first and the third circular quartiles:

```
library(circular)

get_circular_median <- function(vector){
  circular <- circular(vector, units=c("hours"), rotation=c("clock"), modulo=c("2pi"))
  circular_median <- (median.circular(circular))[[1]]
  return(circular_median)
}

get_third_circular_quartile <- function(vector){
  circular <- circular(vector, units=c("hours"), rotation=c("clock"), modulo=c("2pi"))
  third_quartile <- quantile.circular(circular, probs=c(0.25))[[1]]
  return(third_quartile)
}

get_first_circular_quartile <- function(vector){
  circular <- circular(vector, units=c("hours"), rotation=c("clock"), modulo=c("2pi"))
  first_quartile <- quantile.circular(circular, probs=c(0.75))[[1]]
  return(first_quartile)
}
```

Is there a way to use custom median and quartile functions for ggplot2's `boxplot()` function?

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: https://www.r-bloggers.com/boxplot-with-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-ggplot2-plus-jitter/

Comment: Thank you for the link, it helps me a lot.

Comment: I have same problem as you. You can use it.[How to mimic geom_boxplot() with outliers using geom_boxplot(stat = “identity”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078797/how-to-mimic-geom-boxplot-with-outliers-using-geom-boxplotstat-identity)